# how a server call an endpoint https or http

Tags: http, https

I have a question concerning calling api endpoint. For example if I define a `SERVER_ENDPOINT=https://my_api_site` I just wonder how the server call that endpoints:

1. will it always call with `https://my_api_site`
2. or it will sometimes call `https://my_api_site` and sometime call `http://my_api_site`

If the second option happens, then in what situation the server decide to call http instead of https.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The server (i guess you're referring to mod_proxy and ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse options) calls the domain you specify using the protocol you specify. It doesn't change anything by itself.